# Script Injection on random pages

Tags: iis, hacking, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I am currently running a Windows 2003 server with IIS 6.0. 
It seems to be that one of the website has been 'hacked'.

`<script src=http://<SOME WEIRD WEBSITE>></scipt>`

A script tag linking to a malicious js file is inserted at the top of various ASP pages only during the weekends.
I have checked each pages and they contain no such tags.

The pages only INSERT or UPDATE data in the database and does not read/print any data from the database. However most the pages do get POST/GET data passed to them.

I have tried reinstalling IIS but still having the same issue.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend formatting the server and reinstalling Windows.  Sounds like you've got a virus on the server.

Comment: Is there any other things I could try before formatting the server? :(

Comment: Not to guarantee that the problem has been solved. After formatting the server you'll need to make sure that whatever attack vector was used is also closed off.